# Vue: Keep the same message until component is completely hidden

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have following Vue component.
When the button is clicked, it shows my-popup that shows message depending on the `world` flag.
When my-popup is closed, it switches `world` flag true/false.
Also, on closing, my-popup fades out and takes 2~3 seconds to completely dissapear.

Problem is, right after the onOK() method is fired, I can see the message on the closing my-popup changes as well.
(ex. If current message is `hello world`, it is changed to `hello universe` when fading out)

Is there any way to switch `world` flag and still hold the same message until the popup is closed?

```
<template>
  <button @click="popupShown = true">hello</button>
  <my-popup :value="popupShown", title="HELLO" @ok="onOK()">hello {{world ? 'world' : 'universe'}}</mypopup>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      popupShown: false,
      world: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onOK () {
      this.world = !world
      this.popupShown: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: pls show us the component `my-popup` as well

Comment: Wrap `this.world = !world` in `this.$nextTick( () => { this.world = !world })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming that you are using Vue Transition in `my-popup` component)

What I notice about Vue transition is that, on a transition for hiding something, using

- **v-if** : reactive values would **stop** updating
- **v-show** : reactive values would **continue** updating

demo: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/BxqGgB

Therefore, if you are using `v-show` in the transition in `my-popup`, simply changing it to `v-if` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation with the nice example.